# CollapsiblePanelExtender inside a ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, listview

I am trying to have a collapsible panel inside of a listview item.  In the item template, I have a panel, and a collapsible panel extender.  In order to set the attributes TargetControlID, CollapseControlID, etc., I need the ClientIDs that are generated after databinding for each of the listview items.  Does anyone know how I can set those attributes client-side?

I've tried various things along the lines of the following:

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Panel ID="ManagingPanel" runat="server">
  </asp:Panel>
  <asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender runat="server" TargetControlID='<%="ManagingPanel.ClientID" %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

***SOLUTION** - Turns out you do not need to use the ClientID.  The Extender will recognize that its target is inside the same listview item.*

```
<asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender runat="server" TargetControlID="ManagingPanel" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you do not need to use the ClientID. The Extender will recognize that its target is inside the same listview item.

```
<asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender runat="server" TargetControlID="ManagingPanel" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have create a custom user control that includes the CollapsiblePanelExtender and every other think that I like to show, a complex html struct, and then I have include this control in the repeater.

The repeater pass the data that I need to render my custom control, and then the custom control render its self in every line of the repeater, and all is working fine.

something like

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <uc1:MyCustonControl ID="lPro" runat="server" data="<%#PassData%>"  />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```